# Does Entityframework auto assign navigation properties on create

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I run the below mentioned code EF saves the `PersonAddress` with the correct `PersonId`. I have **NOT** added the `PersonAddress` entities to the `Person` entity, even though I have not done this the records in my database are linked correctly.

My question is: Does EF **automatically** add the related entities even though I have not specified the entity that it belongs to? And if so can this not cause **unwanted** entity relations?

**Update**

It seems that the entities are saved correctly for the following reasons:

1. When creating entity `Person` the `PersonId` field is 0
2. `PersonAddress.PersonId` is also 0 at the time of creation.

By manually setting the `Person.PersonId` to any value at the time of creation, and then setting `PersonAddress.PersonId` to that same value of `Person.PersonId` EF saves the data correctly as they share the same `PersonId`.

So technically EF does **not** add the related entities automatically, they are related as they share the same `PersonId`.

Please see code below as reference:

```
        using (var context = new Models.TestEntities())
        {
            var person = context.People.Create();

            var postalAddress           = context.PersonAddresses.Create();
            postalAddress.AddressLine1  = "PostalAddressLine1";

            var residentialAddress          = context.PersonAddresses.Create();
            residentialAddress.AddressLine1 = "ResidentialAddressLine1";

            context.People.Add(person);
            context.PersonAddresses.Add(postalAddress);
            context.PersonAddresses.Add(residentialAddress);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

When I add an extra `Person` to the code, I get the following error:
[image]

Code:

```
        using (var context = new Models.TestEntities())
        {
            var person  = context.People.Create();
            var person2 = context.People.Create();

            var postalAddress           = context.PersonAddresses.Create();
            postalAddress.AddressLine1  = "PostalAddressLine1";

            var residentialAddress          = context.PersonAddresses.Create();
            residentialAddress.AddressLine1 = "ResidentialAddressLine1";

            context.People.Add(person);
            context.People.Add(person2);                

            context.PersonAddresses.Add(postalAddress);
            context.PersonAddresses.Add(residentialAddress);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

As the error specified Entityframework can now not determine to whom the `PersonAddress` entities belong.

I can resolve this by modifying the code as below:

```
        using (var context = new Models.TestEntities())
        {
            var person  = context.People.Create();
            var person2 = context.People.Create();

            var postalAddress           = context.PersonAddresses.Create();
            postalAddress.AddressLine1  = "PostalAddressLine1";

            var residentialAddress          =    context.PersonAddresses.Create();
            residentialAddress.AddressLine1 = "ResidentialAddressLine1";

            context.People.Add(person);
            context.People.Add(person2);

            person.PersonAddresses.Add(residentialAddress);
            person.PersonAddresses.Add(postalAddress);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Please see the EDMX below:

[image]

Please see SQL script used to create the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
   PersonId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] PRIMARY KEY,
   FirstName VARCHAR(250)
)

CREATE TABLE PersonAddress
(
   PersonAddressId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [PK_PersonAddress]     PRIMARY KEY,
  PersonId INT NOT NULL,
  AddressLine1 VARCHAR(250)
)

  ALTER TABLE PersonAddress
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_PersonAddress_Person] FOREIGN KEY(PersonId)
  REFERENCES [Person](PersonId)
```

Please see Id columns screenshots below:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Please see SQL Server Profiler trace below:

`Person`:
[image]

`PersonAddress`:
[image]

`PersonAddress`:
[image]

Please see the inserted records in SQL:

`Person`:
[image]

`PersonAddress`:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: No. EF does should not tie together both objects. Please post your DB model (specially definition of `Person` and `PersonAddress`) as this issue is probably caused by wrong DB model.

Comment: I don't see any good changes between first and second snippet that could solve the error (`DbUpdateException`) in the snippet.

Comment: Can I post an image of the DB model as these are the only two tables?

Comment: Jenish Rabadiya - Please see that in the last code snippet I call `person.PersonAddresses.Add` instead of `context.PersonAddresses.Add(`

Comment: How are the IDs for PersonAddress generated? IDENTITY?

Comment: Yes the PersonAddress Id is IDENTITY, Please see updated question with attached SQL script used to create  the two tables.

Comment: Check that EF is configured to use those identity values. The StoregeneratedPattern should be configured correctly.

Comment: Please see updated question with attached screenshots of the Id columns properties.

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt Not related to the question but note to add @ before the name of user in comment so that user will be notified about your comment.

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt This is not possible. you should have got an exception. What are the Id of person.Id and personAddress.personid When you inserted it with first snippet ?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya I am not receiving any errors on the first snippet. The `personAddress.personId` in the database is the value of the inserted `person`. I have now added multiple person records through sql to get the `personId` incremented, after doing this the first snippet still succeeds in linking the new `person` and `personAddress`. If you have SQL profiler please run a trace and you will see that the sql generated to insert the `personAddress` entities will have the correct `personId` as a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Here's what happens:

```
var person = context.People.Create();
```

A `Person` is created having `PersonId` = 0.

```
var postalAddress           = context.PersonAddresses.Create();
postalAddress.AddressLine1  = "PostalAddressLine1";
var residentialAddress          = context.PersonAddresses.Create();
residentialAddress.AddressLine1 = "ResidentialAddressLine1";
```

Addresses are created, also having `PersonId` = 0.

```
context.People.Add(person);
context.PersonAddresses.Add(postalAddress);
context.PersonAddresses.Add(residentialAddress);
```

EF has executed *relationship fixup*, i.e. it has matched the addresses' `PersonId`s and the `Person`'s `PersonId` (all 0) and established an association between them.

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

The database has assigned an identity value to `Person.PersonId`. EF read it back from the database into the entities.

In the second snippet there are two `Person`s having `PersonId` = 0, so now EF doesn't know which person to associate the addresses with.

#### What to do

Clearly, this is unexpected behavior. The best thing is to associate the entities explicitly, if they are intended to be related, as in your third snippet.

Once you know about these automatic associations you may want to prevent them by assigning a different default value to `Person.PersonId` other than 0, e.g. -1. Now EF won't match this id with any other foreign value having the default for integers, 0.

Comment: setting it -1 throws error insert conflicted.... that means it works. great answer!

Comment: An answer to the always interesting question (that just cost me a couple of hours) "How did that ever work?"

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the scenario by creating a new project against a new database that I created with your script.  I then generated a model against it leaving, all the defaults.

Here is the code I used to create the person and addresses.

```
        var entities = new TestEntities();

        var person = entities.People.Create();
        person.FirstName = "xxx";
        entities.People.Add(person);

        var address1 = entities.PersonAddresses.Create();
        address1.AddressLine1 = "Line1";
        entities.PersonAddresses.Add(address1);

        var address2 = entities.PersonAddresses.Create();
        address2.AddressLine1 = "Line1";
        entities.PersonAddresses.Add(address2);

        entities.SaveChanges();
```

I can confirm that this code does indeed run and insert a person and two addresses linked to that person.  It definitely looks like EF wires it up if there is only one entity that it could possibly link to.  I'm not sure if that is supposed to be a feature, but it can make for some nasty surprises.

Comment: I agree, this can lead to unwanted relationships being created.

Comment: Interestingly, I tried it with a nullable PersonId on the Address.  In this case the PersonId stays null.  This makes me suspect even more that this is supposed to be a feature.

Comment: This does not provide answer to question.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya The question was "Does Enityframework automatically add the related entities even though I have not specified the entity that it belongs to?".  I answered " It definitely looks like EF wires it up if there is only one entity that it could possibly link to."  I'm not sure why you think that doesn't answer the question.  If the question was why EF does this it would be a different matter.

Comment: If that would have been the question it has already an answer in OP's post in question it does. First snippet works well.

Answer (score 0):

No EF cannot add automatically related entity if you are not specify what is the second entity, the reason is data integrity constraints in the database,hope this helps.

Comment: Well if EF does not do this automatically why does my first snippet of code work?

Comment: As i see it didn't work, did you try to insert one object PersonAddresses ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you attach the two person entities to the context

```
context.People.Add(person);
context.People.Add(person2);
```

And here you attach the two addresses to the first person entity

```
person.PersonAddresses.Add(residentialAddress);
person.PersonAddresses.Add(postalAddress);
```

So basically you tell the Entity Framework that you want to map the two addresses to the first person. If you do not do this, Entity Framework will not map them unless in the adresses you enter the personID manually

In your first code you only create person and addresses and attempt to add them to the database. There are no mapping between them and Entity Framework does not know of they should be linked.

Comment: The first snippet of code does work, EF links them up correctly. Please run the first snippet of code and you will see the result.